# About Openfire and Xmpp

Tags: android, ios, xmpp, backend, openfire

i just asked later about wanting to do a backend server for an instant message application, reading a lot there is less and less tutorials or books on how to achieve this, now with the growing tendency from the BaaS services. As i am using the XMPP Protocol to communicate my application, i found in the way Openfire.

I'm not a server guy, i know a little about this, so my questions are:

What others technologies do i need to accomplish my goal to create an instant message app?
Does Openfire create a consistent database for registered users?
Can i send files like images, videos, sharing contact info, etc?
Can i use apple push notifications?
Could i consider the same server for use it with an Android version of my app?
Should i stick to Parse.com?
If i use Parse.com, can i still use XMPP or is not necessary?

Hope you can help me, because i'm having a bad time with the server side!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do all these things. But you need to create plugins for some of the functionalists   like push notification

Comment: Hello Jas! another question, does Openfire implements a database for handling the data?

Comment: yes, while installing openfire it ask for embedded or external database